# Shorten indicator title view on chart

Tags: charts, title, tradingview-api, indicator

I'm new in pinescript and I'd like to view only the title of my indicator, i.e. Multibox USA, and not all input of sessions. How could solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status line is composed of the indicator name, user input arguments, and indicator values.

From Pine Script, you can shorten [the indicator name](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_indicator) or control the [display of plot values](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_display%7Bdot%7Dstatus_line).

From a user point of view, you can configure all the status lines from the [chart settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpgUx.png). Or granularly, you can control the display of an indicator values from its settings.